# Java Millis to nanoseconds

Tags: java

I have just started to learn Java, and I want to make random array and to measure time. I used `System.currentTimeMillis();` at the beginning of filling my array, and the same at then and. Then I wanted to convert milliseconds to nanoseconds and used `long total=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(time1);` but trouble occurred:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

long time1,time2,time3;
int [] array =  new int[10];
Random rand =new Random(100);
time1=System.currentTimeMillis();
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
array[i]=rand.nextInt(100);
}
time2=System.currentTimeMillis()-time1;

    long total=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(time1);
    System.out.println("Time is:"+time1
    );

}

}
```

In the end I got 'Time is:1361703051169;' I think that something's wrong with this.

Comment: The word "массив" translates as an "array", not as "massive" (which  means "массивный" :)

Comment: I think you need `System.out.println("Time is:"+total);` and change total to use `time2` not `time1`

Comment: Do you want to tell us what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to rewrite your code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start, end, difference;

    start = System.nanoTime();

    //code to meassure here

    end = System.nanoTime();
    difference = end - start;

    System.out.println("Time taken:" + difference);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, instead of using

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

you can use

```
System.nanoTime()
```

That provides the time in nanoseconds, without having to do any conversion

Also i think this maybe wrong:

```
long total=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(time1);
System.out.println("Time is:"+time1);
```

Maybe you wanted to print `total` instead of `time1`?

**EDIT**

Please note that, as Mark Rotteveel said, in the `System.nanoTime` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` are different.

From Javadocs:

`System.currentTimeMillis()`

`Returns the current time in milliseconds. 
Note that while the unit of time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger. 
For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of milliseconds.`

and

`System.nanoTime()`

`Returns the current value of the most precise available system timer, in nanoseconds.
This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time.`

Comment: Be aware `System.nanoTime()` does not provide time in the same way that `currentTimeMillis()` does.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes i forgot to say this, i'll update my answer

Comment: ...also OP will most likely print out the difference (`time2`) in nanos between start and end time rather the just printing the start time (`time1`) in nanos.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple conversion with `java.time.Duration` like so: `Duration.ofMillis(numberOfMilliseconds).toNanos()`